# Highstock rangeSelector from days in the future

Tags: highcharts

I have a few rangeSelectors

```
rangeSelector : {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6M'
            }, {
                type: 'ytd',
                text: 'YTD'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 5,
                text: '5y'
            }],
            selected : 3 // year
        },
```

The range will be calculated like: Today - rangeSelector. 
In my chart I have series values in the future e.g. 20.06.2014. Is there any possibility to get the 1 year range from the 20.06.2014 to 20.06.2013 instead of 13.05.2014 (today) to 13.05.2014?

Edit: And is it possible to add a value to a rangeSelector? e.g.

```
{
    type: 'month',
    count: 6, //I would like to add +60days here
    text: '6M'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About first issue, for me it works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/8XLQ3/

And second question, if you want to add 60day,s than just add 3months, like this:

```
{
  type: 'month',
  count: 9,
  text: '6M'
}
```

However I'm pretty sure that's not what you want to achieve.